# The difference between "provide confidential advice" and "provide confidential help"

Tags: differences

Why would it be OK to say "provide confidential advice" but not "provide confidential help"? To me, the latter form seems wrong, but I can't explain why.

Comment: I think this is General Reference. You can provide *confidential **help, advice, assistance, support**, etc.* In context, they may mean the same or different things, but they're all perfectly normal English.

Comment: You might be interested in our proposal for a Q&A site for English language learners. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners

Answer (score 3):

Advice: "an opinion or recommendation offered as a guide to action, conduct"

Help: "to give or provide what is necessary to accomplish a task or satisfy a need; contribute strength or means to"

So I would provide confidential *advice* in a business to business situation, but I would provide confidential *help* with my friend's homework.

Both are correct grammatically, but the latter is probably used less often (there aren't as many situations where help need be confidential).